# Подмена Content

Tags: php, javascript

Есть POST запрос. Надо, чтоб при получении ответа, заменялся Content, нужным мне Content. Как это реализовать?

Comment: Из вопроса ничего не понятно, может конкретизируете или приведете небольшой примерчик, что вы хотите получить?

Comment: ну ваш вопрос может быть только так отвечен:

    Content=ответ

Answer (score 1):

Если POST запрос ajax тогда  помощью jquery вставляем полученый результат в нужный html элемент
    $('div#content').html(result);

Или так:

```
<?php if($_POST): ?>
    ответ пост
<?php else: ?>
    вывод старниччки
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: да не, надо симулировать ответ от сервера.

Comment: на этой стадии